# next js 'yarn start' doesn't run, but I don't have package-lock.json? What else can I remove?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

VS code repository doesn't have the file they are directing me to remove?

How do I find the corrupted file to delete if it's not there?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure to run `yarn install` from inside your project folder, not from your user folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete yarn.lock and install the package again with yarn install